# Android layout event

Tags: android, events, layout

I have a ViewFlipper that contains several Layouts. Is there an event I can set to identify the first time each of the layouts is loaded ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could set an `Animation` for when a view is displayed using `Animation.setInAnimation()`.  Then you could implement the [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) interface to detect when a view is brought in.  I imagine you could add some logic in there to do something the first time each view is loaded.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Man, I start to hate android... So many basic things missing... So many workarounds... So many low level "hacks" to do simple things...